# Are there any disadvantages to using your companions for transporting Power Armor

Tags: fallout-4

After I read that companions don't drain the fusion core of a Power Armor when wearing it, I decided to try giving my armor to Nick so I'll always have it close by if I need it.

But I was wondering if there are any other drawbacks to that. For example, does the Armor get damaged or destroyed when the companion is under fire?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

**It can been inconvenient, but it's worth it.**

I've been leaving a suit of power armor on my companion most of the time, whether I'm wearing one or not. The armor continues to take damage, and needs to be repaired on occasion.

Most of the time that the armor gets damaged, it's because the companion walked right onto a mine or stood next to a car when it exploded. That's annoying and doesn't really have any upside.

If it's actually a combat scenario, then the companion may have a couple pieces of armor break, but if they weren't wearing the armor then that opponent would have likely downed them. I've only had a companion in power armor get downed so that I needed to stimpack them a couple times. I'd say this makes it worth it.

There are other advantages as well.

- Sometimes I take cover behind my companion when they have armor on.
- If I want to drop a long distance, I can take my companion's armor, jump, and then give it back when they catch up.
- If you're overloaded and want to fast travel, you can temporarily get in the armor to increase your carry capacity.
- If you want to move through an intense radiation pocket, you can borrow the armor.
- You look like a badass with a power-armored butler.

### Repairing the Armor

Fixing a companion's armor can be a hassle, but it can be done. You may or may not need to have the companion get out of the armor, depending on your situation.

At a stand with an associated frame, you can only work on the pieces of armor on the frame associated with that stand, or ones in *your inventory*.

**Associating a Frame**

The frame associated with the stand seems to be the last one you were wearing, unless someone else has worn it since. This means that your companion's armor will *not* be associated with the frame while they are wearing it. Walking up to a frame while wearing armor and attempting to interact definitely associates it.

So, if you want to switch the associated frame to your companion's frame you'll have to tell them to get out of it and get in it yourself. To tell them to get out, talk to them. The companion can only enter armor from the back, so if they are backed up against something you might need to tell them to move first, and you might need to move the armor before they can get in it. Companions also sometimes have pathing issues trying to find the back of the armor, so it can be helpful to direct them to "go" to its side, then its back, and then in.

**Fixing Armor not on the Associated Frame**

This only works if you already have a frame associated with the station, so if your companion's frame is the only one around they'll have to get out.

Take the pieces from your companion, walk over to the power armor station, repair them, and then give them back.

To take pieces, trade with your companion and simply take them. To put them back on the frame, trade with your companion, give them the pieces, and tell them to equip them. While doing this, I've noticed a bug regarding the companion's carry weight. It seems like it doesn't subtract the weight of the power armor piece from their encumbrance total when they equip it, so it might tell you that they can't carry any more before you give them all their armor. To fix this, leave the trade dialog, and re-initiate it.

Comment: You can have as many frames and stations as you want.  I have my own personal power armor hangar that would make Tony Stark jealous

Comment: @z' Do you have a different suit associated with each frame? How do you know which one goes with which frame? I often don't walk my suit all the way into the frame, as that makes it hard for my companions to get in.

Comment: My suits are more for display purposes than anything else :p.  If you interact with a frame while in armor you automatically associate them.  And they will snap into position when you open the frame to mod the armor.

Comment: @z' So do all the stations associate with the same armor then?

Comment: each station is associated with their respective suit of armor

Comment: @z' Interesting. That might make things easier. I'll have to try that at some point with my companion's armor, see how things work out.

Comment: Can confirm that the armor is definitely damaged in combat, and the companion can still be downed wearing a full suit.  Source:  Survival difficulty, Legendary Sentry Bot.  Took me more than 30 save scrubs to get a piece of legendary leather, I was so mad.  Full hp (10 End), Psycho and Med-X running, could die in under 5 seconds despite significant cover.  T_T

Comment: @gatherer818 Yeah, I had this happen last night when we were fighting multiple assaultrons and a guy in power armor.

Comment: Are Power Armour stations craftable in your settlements? Which category are they in? Are they with the crafting stations?

Comment: @davidyell yea they are under crafting stations

Answer (score 1):

Yes armour gets damaged while equipped on companions.

came under fire from a Deathclaw and my companion got the arm damaged.

Answer (score 0):

I got Cait to get into some power armour of mine. We got attacked by some super mutants, one was a suicider, and her power armour legs were completely destroyed.

I knew that I can still repair them, but I got back to the power armour station and the legs were no longer equipped. I lost legs to the armor that day, so I just reverted to last save.

Comment: The legs should have been in Cait's inventory.

Comment: Yeah I've had legs go to zero on companions a lot, just check their Apparel tab. In that case the only way to repair the pieces is to put them in your inventory first, they won't appear when you put your companion's armor on the frame. Fortunately it is really easy to give 'em back. I just make a habit of repairing their pieces when I return to base.