# How can I get my follower out of power armor?

Tags: fallout-4

Yesterday I found a second power armor and figured I should to try to get my follower to wear it. She was more than happy to get into the armor, but I can't seem to get her to leave the armor again. 
I've tried using the command dialogs and also tried holding the 'leave power armor' button (E by default on pc), but that didn't do the trick for me.
Thankfully I did a quicksave before I commanded her to try put it on, so I could revert the problem, but I like the idea of us both wearing power armor.

So I would really like to find out how i can get my follower out of power armor?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm certain that this has been answered before, but I can't find the question right now.

Basically you just speak to them and there is a chat option to ask them to get out of the armour. It should replace the 'Relationship' option, under 'Talk'.

Comment: But this doesn't work for followers who are by default in power armor does it?

Comment: No it does not work for Paladin Danse.

Comment: I can't get Preston Garvey to leave his Power Armor either, because when I choose Talk he asks me about a Minuteman quest.  It gets annoying, but hey, he doesn't consume fuel for the thing, might as well let him use it.  I'll put together a full second set eventually.

Comment: So there are just advantages if followers are in power armor? No fuel and they can carry more?

Comment: @gatherer818: Full second set? I have 12 and a chest full of extra parts. I set up a showroom. You will soon have more than you need.

Comment: @Yorik I've heard ^_^ I've got Preston in the basic set from the early main quest, and I've got a half-set I pulled from the National Guard Armory.  Playing on Survival, I don't make much progress, given how often I die :P

Comment: @h0ch5tr4355 No, it doesn't drain fuel, and yes they can carry more. Check out [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/243653/108003) for information on companions in power armor.

Comment: Worked as described. Fun anecdote. After getting a second pair back to base, the base was attacked and a setler entered the armor. He then ran off. Getting him to get out of it again was pretty simple though, just start a conversation...

Comment: Deacon jacked my armor while I was on a terminal.  When I try to talk to him he just says something about how he shouldn't have given me the disable code, but I don't get any options for additional dialog.  After trying just about everything, I ended up just re-loading my game.

Comment: @AdamPlocher Did you read the code? I'm pretty sure that's how you advance that conversation if you didn't succeed at the speech check when he gave it to you.

Answer (score 6):

Just a warning. You can't get Preston Garvey out of power armor if you haven't finished retaking the castle after unlocking it

Comment: This is true of any NPC at a quest stage where they won't have a normal conversation with you, including followers who want to talk about reaching a new stage in your relationship.

Answer (score 6):

I talked to Piper in order for her to exit the power armor that i found, but she would just start talking about friendship, and I couldn't seem to get her out. So I figured out another way method: find another power armor your companion can get in, and order them to enter **that one**. This will essentially make them get out of their current power armor, leaving it available for taking back. Make sure your companion doesn't get into the second power armor when you do this.

Comment: You're a genius. +1

Comment: Deacon just tells me he can't do it :/

Answer (score 2):

If the follower in power armor is NOT your current active follower it seems impossible to force him to leave by talking (did not try if the power core can be taken out then but I did not see the option, maybe requires sneaking). You need to make him/her follow you (dismiss your current follower) and then you can talk and ask to get out of the armor.

Answer (score 1):

On PC version:  I was able to have Cait exit her power armor by initiating conversation with "E", then clicked talk and then clicked "Exit power armor".
The command interface is a bit inconsistent with followers on PC Platform, and I have tried multiple times to get the command to come up for exit armor. Now to add the mods, and see if I can get her back into the armor....

Answer (score 1):

What I've noticed is that when your relationship status is still low with your companion you can't get them out I found two ways of getting them out...

1 - leave them somewhere at sanctuary or red rocket where ever you want to. (just don't forget where and using a small location is wiser)
Then do couple of missions or sleep for +/-48h and she will get out of the suit by herself if there were damaged part she should have them on her just trade and take them back. She is going to dump the suit anywhere found mine on roofs hidden in bushes but it will be within building limits of workshop thats why I said smaller location is wiser.

2 -  Do couple of missions with her to get your relationship status to the highest level then you should be able to ask her to leave the suit when you talk to her. Found this tactic to work with all companions.

just make sure to take out the fusion core before letting them in your suit they don't need it.

And broken parts can be transferred to you for repairs and transferred back to companion wearing suit and equipped.

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

When doing Nick's companion quest, tell Nick to leave his power armor before collecting the last tape, otherwise he will remain in it until the quest is finished.

Got that from a gaming guide as i had the same drama with valentine. Maybe the same for the other cats too

Answer (score 0):

If you tell your follower to hack a terminal or do some lockpicking, they apparently leave the suit and you can access it.

Answer (score 0):

Approach the NPC you want to get out of the power armor by walking up to them.  Open console with `;` and left mouse click the NPC. Type `callfunction "actor.switchtopowerarmor"` in the console and hit return.  Close console by typing `.

Answer (score -1):

Command your companion, then talk, then hit A for exit power armour. I saw above something about enemy power armour. You can only take the add ons from the power armour frame. Not the frame itself. Oh and be warned not to use your best power armour.... Piper decided to exit out of hers somewhere in game and by the time I realised, I had no idea where it was.

Comment: There should be a power armor symbol on the map whereever there is armor owned by you.

Answer (score -1):

Best and easiest way I have found is to rest until night time (2 am to 5 am) dismiss companion then assign them to a bed. I have yet to have one not climb out of the power armor to sleep so far.

Answer (score -2):

If it's an enemy you have to kill him, if it's your companion you must leave/dismiss him and then recollect him(always take the power core out)

Comment: Not true, you just have to talk to your companion and tell him to get out. See other answer

Comment: Also, you can make [enemies step out of their Power Armor by stealing their Fusion Core](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IkS5f9Y9G3w) (can be seen around 2:10).