# Power armor and safe storage

Tags: fallout-4

Does anyone know how many suits of power armor I can leave at red rocket truck stop before I should worry that they will spawn away. Note that none have fusion cores in them as I took them out when I store them there. I'm looking at 9 suits of power armor there now

Comment: Actually a great question I hadn't thought of. Good to know info - Thanks for asking :)

Comment: REMOVE THE FUSION CORES! Settlers will climb inside if under attack and the armor has a core. Even Carla will take a suit and she's harder to get out

Answer (score 11):

Power armor in settlements will never disappear. You can have as many suits of power armor as you like in a settlement; there is no limit, even without fusion cores.

Please note that this only applies to settlements. If you leave power armor in the wilderness, it will despawn after a given time.

Comment: I think wilderness is something different than villages you own. If you store stuff in a random container, it might disappear too, but if you store it in a village, it will be there forever.

Comment: @kalina well, you have enough rep to edit my post if some information is missing. :P Did that for now, but don't hesitate to add information if you think it's needed.^^

Comment: @kalina I still think that this should belong to the answer. Even though the asker itself didn't ask it, it might be useful for other people who might look into the question in the future.

Comment: @YUNOWORK, Do you need to store them at power armor stations, or can you leave them out anywhere, as long as they are within your settlement?

Comment: @DangerZone as long as you place them inside the green borders, they won't disappear. Ther power armor station is not responsible for saving their location